# Erro ao criar projeto Maven no Eclipse

Tags: java, maven

O erro acontece assim que crio o projeto Maven, utilizo o Eclipse Oxygen.
[image: Erro que acontece ao criar o projeto Maven]

Comment: Se puderem me ajudar a solucionar o problema ficarei muito grato, preciso começar esse projeto o quanto antes para cumprir prazos. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minha sugestão é remover a dependencia que está gerando o conflito do seu repositório local

> .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin

Depois faça build do projecto para ver se o problema ficou resolvido.